# Selecting specific column in ORM relationship Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel

I have an order table with a primary key **id** and another table trips. I trip can have many orders. I have defined the relationship in this way

```
public function orders_currency() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Order', 'trip_id', 'id')->select('id', 'converted_currency_code');
}
```

Although I know that, I have to select id of the order table in order to get the result, that's why I am mentioning to select the id of the order table. 
Despite this, I am getting the **orders_currency** index empty. Which angle am I missing in this case?
Any clue will be appreciated.

Comment: you have to select all the ids which ur joining. 

show us how you are calling the orders_currency in ur query

Comment: I think you shouldn't select when defining a relationship. Move your select outside?

Comment: theres no issues using select when defining relationship.

Comment: public static function getTripByUserId($id) {
        return Trip::where('user_id', '=', $id)
                        ->with('user.profile')
                        ->with('address_to')
                        ->with('address_from')
                        ->with('orders_currency')
                        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                        ->get();
    }

Comment: Try this

`public function orders_currency() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Order', 'id', 'trip_id')->select('id', 'converted_currency_code');
}`

Comment: @Jigs1212  this not working

Comment: in App\Order which other id u are referencing ? select that too.

Comment: I have also check this method, i have also tried by selecting attributes in with() closure, but not worked for me.

Comment: try `pluck` instead of `select`

Comment: I got the solution by doing this way
        public function orders_currency() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Order', 'trip_id', 'id')- 
        >select('trip_id','converted_currency_code');
    }
i have has to select refrencing key in this case.

Comment: @Jigs1212 thanks for guiding me

Comment: yes thats the way do post ur answer :)

Comment: @Jigs1212 i have posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by doing this way

```
public function orders_currency() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Order', 'trip_id', 'id')
    ->select('trip_id','converted_currency_code');
}
```

I had to select referencing key in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up the model correctly?
You'd do something like this in your model script I suppose

```
class Trips extends Model
{

     public function orders() {
        return $this->hasMany('Order');
    }
```

Comment: I have to select specific columns